# ConEmu: quake style instance + classic window instance

Tags: windows, conemu

I already have a running quake-style instance of ConEmu. The problem is that I would like to launch another non-quake (running in normal window) instance. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do not to look at switches? `ConEmu.exe -?`

At least you may use `-noquake -nosingle` switches. Or another named configuration with `-config <name>`. Or load config from another xml `-loadcfgfile <ConEmuXml>`.

Comment: Sorry for the not very bright question and thanks for the cool answer!

Comment: /NoQuake doesn't really work cause Single instance mode is forced with quake mode. So if I have ConEmu running (in quake mode) and I execute Conemu.exe -noquake, the already existing instance is shown. I used the solution with multiple configs - I have one config in registry and another one in an xml file. A disadvantage is that I generally want to share large part of the configuration which i cannot do atm.

Comment: Answer updated. `-nosingle`